# Is there a way to write regular matching in fish shell?

Tags: glob, fish

The files have a common pattern.

```
feed_predict.data.4.202.0
feed_predict.mdl.4.202.0
feed_predict.so.4.202.0
feed_predict.xml.4.202.0
```

I want to move files in batches.

```
for x in feed_predict{.*}4.202.0;
    //ls $x //nothing prints here
    sudo mv $x $1.4.17.0;
end
```

But $x is empty here.

Comment: It should be `for x in feed_predict*4.202.0; do.... done`

Comment: BTW, this is not a regex issue, it is a glob and generally *nix/fish issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *basename* with the old suffix to strip it from the filename and then concatenate it with the new suffix:

```
for x in feed_predict.*.4.202.0;
    sudo mv $x (basename $x .4.202.0).4.17.0
end
```